# TypeORM Repository find options

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm trying to follow this information http://typeorm.io/#/find-options but I'm unable to specify any of the listed options (select, relations, order) and getting the following error:

`Object literal may only specify known properties and 'where' does not exist in type 'FindConditions<xxx>'`

where becomes relations or order depending on first option specified.

```
this.reportRepository.find({
  where: {},
  relations: ['fss'],
  order: {date_created: 'DESC'},
});
```

TypeOR@0.2.7

Comment: Error was a bit misleading, turns out I used a database column name and not entity property name in the order clause and got this error as a result. So error pointing to where and not date_created caused me some grief.

Comment: You haven't specified any conditions inside your `where` so that will probably cause the issue.